# Accept only subdomain in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy set up in nginx for a node.js server.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name sub.domain.tld;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

It works all fine and dandy, however, I *only* want `sub.domain.tld` to work. Opening up  `domain.tld` in a browser still routes to the node.js server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to add this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.tld;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: This worked, and I expanded my problem/solution to include other subdomains. `server_name ~^(.*)?.?domain.tld;`. Doesn't seem as elegant of a solution, though.

Comment: But this will allow all subdomains right?
hello.domain.tld
fake.domain.tld


Is there any way to allow only one subdomain ?